# how to replace a string which is not integer using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i have use this regex try to replace a string which is not a integer ,however it replace when it is a integer.

```
 this.v=function(){this.value=this.value.replace(/^(-?[1-9]\d*|0)$/,'');}
```

**what is the opposite regex?** :what is the regex for replace a string which is not a **integer**    with "".

> eg:if user entered string is not -2,0,1,123 such like that i want clear the input.if string like 2e3r,2.5,-1.3 the input will be clear
>   value

Comment: Somewhat unclear, but if you just want to check that the user input is not a number, there's a function for that -> `isNaN(this.value)`

Comment: `\D`: Match non-number `\d`: match number

Comment: decimal is not allowed.eg:1.20;2.5

Comment: Use `<input type="number" />` or `<input type="text" pattern="\d+" />`

Answer (score 0):

You could sanitize user input using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) methods. For example:

```
    var normalInput = "1";
    normalInput = parseInt(normalInput, 10);
    console.log(normalInput); // prints 1

    var wrongInput = "12a23-24";
    wrongInput = parseInt(wrongInput, 10);
    console.log(wrongInput); // prints 12 (stops after first not valid number)
```

Or something like that:

```
var myInput = "21312312321",
        processedInput = Number(myInput);

if(processedInput !== NaN){ // if number given is a valid number return it (also works for float input)
    console.log(processedInput);
    return processedInput;
}
else{ // otherwise return an empty string
    return "";
}
```

Jsfiddle [example1](https://jsfiddle.net/r3zs9ywg/1/) [example2](https://jsfiddle.net/r3zs9ywg/3/).

Comment: thanks i have solved the question ,in my method decimals is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

If you must use regex then the following should work. Not tested for efficiency, just thrown together.

```
var numbersOnly = function(number_string) {
    var re = /(\+?|\-?)([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)*/g;
    return number_string.match(re);
}

numbersOnly('pears1.3apples3.2chinesefood-7.8');
// [ '1.3', '3.2', '-7.8' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this one by changing the function logic:

```
onblur="(this.v=function(){var re=/^(-?[1-9]\d*|0)$/;if(!re.test(this.value)){this.value=''}}).call(this)
```

Comment: Doesn't match decimals.

Comment: the method i want decimals is not allowed

Comment: Your example has a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all non-digit characters in the string:

```
this.v=function(){this.value=this.value.replace(/\D+/g,'');}
```